# Are you going to use self-defined error fields or those of OAuth 2.0 when you are building restful services with OAuth 2.0?

Tags: error-handling, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

It's a little hard to explain it well.

1. When building a restful web service, you normally will define two fields for errors:  error_code and error_msg
2. When using OAuth2.0 with grant_type = password, you will see that it has already defined such 2 fields. For example,  {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"xxx"} . The spelling has to be exact like this because it is restricted by OAuth 2.0 protocol.

The question is, when you are combining the 2 into one server-side application, are you normally going to just use OAUTH's {"error":"my-biz-error-code","error_description":"xxx"}  for your biz error response, or you'd rather define two fields on your own such as {"biz_err":"my-biz-error-code","biz_err_desc":"xxx"} ?

According to your experience, which approach will make the client development easier?

A further (and optional) question is, if you are a swagger.io user, what way will you choose to generate better documents?

Answer (score 0):

I now answer this question myself:  I define my biz error object whose error fields are the superset of oauth2 ones. Oauth2's error_description is taken as the "error msg for developers" in my error response object.

public class FoErrorResult {

```
@JsonProperty("error")
private String errorCode;

@JsonProperty("error_description")
private String devErrMsg;

@JsonProperty("error_description_for_user")
private String userErrMsg;

@JsonProperty("exception_id")
private String exceptionId;
```

}